# Install Linux on flash disk like internal disk

Tags: linux, ubuntu, operating-system

guys I have an issue with Linux
I wanna install Linux on flash disk like internal disk
actually I wanna install it with presentation space
I did it but it limited with 4 gig space.
I wanna use all space of flash disk and do my works on it like an internal partition
like a really OS

Comment: Can you please explain some more; what do you mean by presentation space? Is it important that you have one single partition? Is it your flash disk that is only 4GB?

Comment: This should be asked on https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

In the normal installation process, you will be asked to select the partition on which you would like to install Linux.

The option for bootable USB will be visible with a warning sign. In some flavours, it may be hidden however, you can still install it. Simply click on the USB drive partition and Linux can be installed on it.

Make sure you have at least 16GB USB Flash drive to run your Linux smoothly.